# NameError on executing 'rails s'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started this tutorial for Rails. I just created the app and was going to test the default welcome page and this happened:

```
D:\Programming\Rails Projects\simpleCMS>rails server
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:7:in `<class:Template>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:6:in `<module:WebConsole>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
            from D:/Programming/Rails Projects/simpleCMS/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
            from bin/rails:4:in `require'
            from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My gemfile (without the comments):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
    gem 'byebug'
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: What is on line 7 of `config/application.rb`?

Comment: `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`

Comment: Try commenting the line out, so it will not run, and add this line instead: `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)`. Not sure it will work, but your syntax does not sound very familiar to me...

Comment: exactly same error as before @RubyRacer. As for the syntax I haven't even gotten around to editing even a single line of code so this is all what Rails did on its own.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure about it, as I said. Have you run `bundle install` before trying to run the server?

Comment: yeah, tried it after making your edit as well, same result

Comment: @RabeezRiaz Did you create the Rails project with `rails new`?

Comment: @RabeezRiaz So you just did `rails new`, then `cd` into the new directory, then `rails s` and you get this error? What version of rails are you using? How did you install rails?

Comment: yes @eirikir I created the project, tried to start the server and got the error. I have Rails version 4.2.3 and installed it using `gem install rails`

Comment: @RabeezRiaz I just tried this on my local and did not have any problems, so its not the Rails version. What OS are you on? Can you paste your Gemfile here?

Comment: Windows 10
I'll add the gemfile to the OP @eirikir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall `railties` gem because just uninstalling the `rails` gem doesn't work. Then install an older version of the `rails` gem (4.0.0 in my case because that was the one from the tutotial).

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to bind an ip address
why dont you try this:
**rails server -b localhost**

Comment: You should explain more about the solution.

Comment: i assumed he already did db:migrate & db:seed therefore he did rails server; i took a saas course online before an remembered that sometimes depending on where you are running your app you might need to add "-b 127.0.0.1"(ie local host) however if you use cloud9 or nitrous then it'd be different but still -b ###(some ip address) here. clear enough?