# WeBrick does not bootup, gives an error white accessing new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick, nameerror

I'm getting an error when I try to boot up WeBrick.
When I type `rails server`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:423:in `<class:Base>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:417:in `<module:ActionMailer>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb:59:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
#gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
#gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
#gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
#gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
#gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

#group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  #gem 'byebug'
#end

#group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  #gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
#end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Can anybody help me fix this?

PS: I am running on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'rack', '~> 1.6.4'
```

and then run:

```
bundle install
```

and see if that fixes your issue.

#### Update

If the above does not work, try uninstalling `railties` gem. Then install an older version of the `rails` (rails version `4.0.0` was used in the  from the tutorial). The issue is due to the version mismatch/incompatibility of some of your gems.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766656/nameerror-on-executing-rails-s
This seems to be the same issue as yours. Same tutorial as well.