# NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I upgraded my project from rails 3.2 to rails 4.2. Everything works fine in local, server, test, precompile assets.

But when I deploy it to production, I get this error when `assets:precompile`. I tried it in local, it works ok.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:204:in `<class:Base>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:164:in `<module:ActionController>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cancancan-1.13.1/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:394:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cancancan-1.13.1/lib/cancan.rb:5:in `require'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cancancan-1.13.1/lib/cancan.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cancancan-1.13.1/lib/cancancan.rb:1:in `require'
/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cancancan-1.13.1/lib/cancancan.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/home/app/ryeboy/releases/20151024080811/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/app/ryeboy/releases/20151024080811/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/app/ryeboy/releases/20151024080811/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

I can see the `ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper` file under `/home/app/ryeboy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/`, I tried comment out the line in the `lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40`

```
include ActiveSupport::Benchmarkable
include ActiveModelHelper # this line.
include AssetTagHelper
include AssetUrlHelper
```

Then the error became `NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`. So I think this might be some loading sequence problem. Unfortunately, I can't think out a way to debug this. please help.

btw, I'm using ruby 2.0.0, use rvm in server.

Thanks for your help :p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32412231/2057388

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried that before ask this..

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with my RVM configuration. I set up a new server and install ruby directly. everything works fine..